# Laravel 4: Queues and Multiple Listeners

Tags: php, laravel

If I am running Beanstalk with Supervisor on a server with a Laravel 4 application, and I want it to process all queues asynchronously -- as many as it can at the same time -- can I have multiple listeners running at the same time?  Will they be smart enough to not "take" the same to-do item from the queue, or will they all reach for the same one at the same time, and thus not work in the way I'm wanting?  **In short, I want to use Queues to process multiple tasks at a time -- can this be done?**

```
php artisan queue:listen && php artisan queue:listen && php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: I am fairly sure that you would have to use push queues which is only supported with the iron.io driver in Laravel. Not a bad alternativ though.

Answer (score 5):

> In short, I want to use Queues to process multiple tasks at a time -- can this be done?

In short - yes it can be done. Every job taken by a worker is locked until it's release. It means that other workers will get different jobs to process.

IMO it's better to configure Supervisor to run multiple `queue:work` command. It will take only one job, process it and stop execution.
It's not encouraged to run PHP scripts in a infinite loop (as `queue:listen` does), because after some time they can have memory issues (leaks etc).

You can configure Supervisor to re-run finished workers.